# Array in array Twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

A small Twig question regarding array in array access. I have the following script, which is essentially listing categories, and then the subcategories associated to each category.

```
{% for category in categories %}

    <li>
        <a href="#">{{ category.name }}</a>

        {% if category.subcategories|length > 0 %}

        {% set subcategories  = category.subcategories %}

        <ul>
            {% for subcategory in subcategories %}

            <li>
                <a href="#">{{ subcategory.name }}</a>
            </li>

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

The script above does not display subcategories and I have no clue as to why. The main problem is the fact that the for loop is never accessed. Dumping the subcategories variable right after setting it reveals the expected, that it holds the correct array, with one element.

Any ideas?

Dumping the subcategories variable reveals:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'Dolls' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'Test' (length=4)
```

Comment: This code is good. If your category has one or more subcategories, this code should print them. Revise you really have subcategories.

Comment: Hey, provided a dump() of the subcategories variable. Still not luck.

Comment: Why don't you use directly `{% for subcategory in category.subcategories %}`?

Comment: Tried that initially, but thought that I was maybe asking too much of Twig to some extent. Anyway, found answer, thanks for the optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was actually not related to Twig at all in this case, but to a class that was applied to the **li** item that held everything together, that only displayed the content when a specific class was applied to it.

In a very bizarre way, the node simply got deleted by a JS when the class was not applied, so firebug would not pick it up. Eventually stumbled into it on the page source, and that's how I got to the solution.